# Unable to debug java project on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, debugging, intellij-idea

I am unable to debug my project on IntelliJ. I am getting following error:

```
Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 5s 496ms
Error:ajc: Missing message: configure.incompatibleComplianceForTarget in: org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.messages
Error:Internal error: bad args
```

I tried to google but didn't get any helpful resource.

Comment: Are you passing any arguments in the main method?

Comment: I googled an immediately found this:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206250209-AJC-failure